# Creating a unique ID using first 3 character of last name and a sequence number

Tags: sql-server

I have this employee table which I want every employee to have a unique ID using the 3 first letters of their name plus a sequence number in SQL Server.
I don't remember at all how to do this I haven't used SQL in a year and kinda forgot everything.
Can anyone refresh my mind on how to do this. Google has been of no help on this matter. Thanks

Comment: Use an identity column. Slap the first three letters on the beginning. Ta-da.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I suggest that the numeric portion of your identifier be unique in and of itself, in case the employee gets married and changes their last name. The prefix can still appear to the left of it, but should not be necessary to be unique.

If you agree with this design, then you can simply use a numeric identity column on the Employee table and combine that with the last name when retrieving the data, using a computed column. I suggest you seed the identity with a value that has enough digits to keep your identifier lengths consistent, so for example to support 90,000 employees you can use a seed of 10,000 which ensures all identifiers are 8 characters long (three letters of the name plus five numeric).

Simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
( 
    EmployeeNo int IDENTITY(10000,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    LastName VarChar(64),
    EmployeeID AS SUBSTRING(UPPER(LastName), 1, 3) + RIGHT('0000' + CONVERT(char(5), EmployeeNo), 5)
)


INSERT Employee (LastName) VALUES ('Smith')

SELECT * FROM Employee
```

Results:

```
EmployeeNo    LastName   EmployeeID
10000         Smith      SMI10000
```

For the purposes of your SQL and table design, your tables should all use `EmployeeNo` as foreign key, since it is compact and unique. Apply the three-letter prefix during data retrieval and only for customer-facing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

@John Wu is right. However, if you don't want to rely on the Employee no then you use `NewID()` function, which will create a unique number always. Below is the code.

```
    CREATE TABLE EmployeeDetails 
( 
    EmployeeCode int IDENTITY(1,1),
    FirstName varchar(50),
    LastName Varchar(50),
    Empid as left(Lastname,3) + convert(varchar(500), newid())
)

INSERT EmployeeDetails VALUES ('Atul', 'Jain')
```

`